# How does the binding function work with core.async?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Is it ok to use binding with core.async? I'm using ClojureScript so core.async is very different.

```
(def ^:dynamic token "no-token")
(defn call 
  [path body] 
  (http-post (str host path) (merge {:headers {"X-token" token}} body)))) ; returns a core.async channel
(defn user-settings
  [req]
  (call "/api/user/settings" req))
; elsewhere after I've logged in
(let [token (async/<! (api/login {:user "me" :pass "pass"}))]
  (binding 
    [token token] 
    (user-settings {:all-settings true})))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ClojureScript<sup>1</sup>, `binding` is basically `with-redefs` plus an extra check that the Vars involved are marked `:dynamic`. On the other hand, `go`s get scheduled for execution<sup>1</sup> in chunks (that is, they may be "parked" and later resumed, and interleaving between `go` blocks is arbitrary). These models don't mesh very well at all.

In short, no, please use explicitly-passed arguments instead.

---

<sup>1</sup> The details are different in Clojure, but the conclusion remains the same.

<sup>2</sup> Using the fastest mechanism possible, `setTimeout` with a time of 0 if nothing better is available.